# How to specify the BusIDs for all framebuffer devices in freebsd?

Tags: x11, freebsd, gui, lxde

I installed lxde this way:

```
sudo pkg install xf86-video-intel
sudo pkg install lxde-mate
cd /usr/home/freebsd
vi .xinitrc
ck-launch-session dbus-launch --exit-with-session
exec startlxde
```

It doesn't matter to write the two lines

```
ck-launch-session dbus-launch --exit-with-session
exec startlxde
```

into one line.

```
exec ck-launch-session dbus-launch --exit-with-session  startlxde
```

And the rc.conf file setting:

```
vi /etc/rc.conf
dbus_enable="YES"

vi /etc/fstab
proc /proc procfs rw 0 0
```

It is time to start lxde to enter into gui.

```
startx

cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | nc termbin.com 9999
https://termbin.com/xctg
```

All the log records uploaded into `https://termbin.com/xctg`.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple to change lines int  `.xinitrc`

ck-launch-session dbus-launch --exit-with-session
exec startlxde

as one line:

```
exec /usr/local/bin/startlxde  --with-ck-launch
```